# Change x-axis date range in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, labeling

unfortunately, I have a simple problem with my `DateListPlot` which I cannot solve on my own (with the guidance online).

The code looks as follows:

```
DateListPlot[{{100, 106, 104, 106, 112, 112, 112, 119, 124, 109, 115,124, 123, 125, 122}, {100, 100, 101, 105, 105, 109, 107, 114, 115,101, 111, 115, 118, 121, 120}, {100, 96, 91, 101, 113, 115, 115,120, 121, 112, 114, 112, 114, 105, 111}, {100, 94, 93, 90, 84, 78,78, 79, 83, 90, 95, 96, 103, 104, 102}, {100, 108, 115, 107, 104,105, 105, 101, 98, 100, 107, 102, 96, 101, 96}, {100, 96, 88, 91,92, 89, 90, 92, 88, 83, 86, 93, 88, 95, 96}, {100, 101, 96, 96, 94,93, 95, 90, 91, 85, 85, 86, 84, 88, 91}, {100, 93, 89, 86, 93, 92,84, 71, 65, 60, 64, 66, 68, 70, 74}, {100, 107, 101, 103, 109,110, 94, 97, 89, 77, 75, 78, 70, 71, 72}, {100, 97, 92, 91, 97, 98, 95, 78, 73, 73, 62, 55, 60, 61, 61}}, {"2000", "2014"}, PlotLegends -> {"DEU:C28", "DEU:C29", "FRA:F", "DEU:F", "USA:O84","DEU:C20", "JPN:F", "USA:C29", "FRA:C29", "USA:F"}, 
 PlotRange -> {40, 140},PlotStyle -> {{None}, {None}, {Dashed}, {Dashed}, {Dashed},{Dashed}, {Dashed}, {None}, {None}, {None}}, PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Development of Top 10 Sectors with Highest Degree in 2000", FontSize -> 12], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {None, "Index"}, ImageSize -> 400]
```

When I plot the line chart, however, just the years 2000, 2005 and 2010 are displayed. This is somehow inconvenient, and I would like to change the scale of the x-axis to a yearly or two-year basis. This means I would like to display every year on the x-axis or every second.

Can someone please help me and tell me, how to change the x-axis labelling accordingly?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `FrameTicks` to specify which ticks and how you want to display (see the docs of `DateListPlot`->Options->FrameTicks). I offer here also a rotation of the ticks by 45 degrees so that they are readable when so dense:

```
ticks = Range[2000, 2014];
center = Row[{#, Invisible[#]}, "\[NegativeThickSpace]"] &;
xticks = Transpose@{Partition[ticks, 1],
     (center@Rotate[#, 45 Degree] &) /@ ticks};
```

Your `DateListPlot` with added `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xticks, Automatic}}`:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @corey979 for your immediate reply! Great!