# Left justified text when using FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I want to draw a `MatrixPlot` and replace the `FrameTicks` with cities names, as shown bellow. The problem is that `FrameTicks` uses the string center to position it in the respective tick, which results in a bad alignment in the top section. How can I set it to use the left justified text?

```
ListaCidades = {"Aveiro", "Açores", "Beja", "Braga", "Bragança", 
   "Castelo Branco", "Coimbra", "Évora", "Faro", "Guarda", "Leiria", 
   "Lisboa", "Madeira", "Portalegre", "Porto", "Santarém", "Setúbal", 
   "Viana do Castelo", "Vila Real", "Viseu"};

MatrixPlot[Data1, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, Style[ListaCidades[[#]], 12]} & /@ Range[20], 
    None}, {None, {#, 
       Rotate[Style[ListaCidades[[#]], 12], 45 Degree]} & /@ 
     Range[20]}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: I think is only similar but not quite the same. That one is asking to align to the center and from the replies I can't figure it out how to adapt to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155151/22013):

```
ListaCidades = {"Aveiro", "Açores", "Beja", "Braga", "Bragança", 
   "Castelo Branco", "Coimbra", "Évora", "Faro", "Guarda", "Leiria", 
   "Lisboa", "Madeira", "Portalegre", "Porto", "Santarém", "Setúbal", 
   "Viana do Castelo", "Vila Real", "Viseu"};
Data1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@ListaCidades, Length@ListaCidades}];

center = Row[{Invisible[#], #}, "\[NegativeThickSpace]"] &;

MatrixPlot[Data1, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, Style[ListaCidades[[#]], 12]} & /@ Range[20], 
    None}, {None, {#, 
       center@Rotate[Style[ListaCidades[[#]], 12], 45 Degree]} & /@ 
     Range[20]}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]